# How to implement Facebook friends leaderboard in android

Tags: java, android, facebook

The android application that I am doing has a Facebook Integration... I am done with the login and post feed dialog.. Now, I want to implement Facebook leaderboard which ranks player in comparison to his/her friends' scores. I don't know where will I start... But as I have stated earlier, I have now the login and post feed dialog which is a good start for now... Any ideas or tutorials for the implementation a Facebook Leaderboard ?

Comment: [Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/) might be useful to you. You could find some examples too.

Comment: @Sahil thanks. Where can I find examples?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can check these [examples](https://developers.facebook.com/samples)